# Stackdriver Extractor fails

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to get stackdriver working with GCE. I went through the standard instructions to install (executing `stack-install.sh --write-gcm`), however it doesn't seem to work at all. When I add monitoring alerts to watch processes, I get:

```
Process monitoring not available for this instance
```

In `/var/log/messages` I see:

```
Mar 28 19:47:59 myhost stackdriver-agent: which: no java in (/root/.gvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin
:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/go/bin:/bin)
Mar 28 19:47:59 myhost stackdriver-agent: Starting stackdriver-collectd: option = PIDFile; value 
= /var/run/stackdriver-agent.pid;
Mar 28 19:47:59 myhost stackdriver-agent: option = Interval; value = 60.000000;
Mar 28 19:47:59 myhost stackdriver-agent: Created new plugin context.
Mar 28 19:47:59 myhost stackdriver-agent: [  OK  ]
Mar 28 19:47:59 myhost collectd[1934]: Initialization complete, entering read-loop.
Mar 28 19:47:59 myhost systemd: Started LSB: start and stop Stackdriver Agent.
Mar 28 19:47:59 myhost collectd[1934]: match_throttle_metadata_keys: 1 history entries, 1 distinc
t keys, 71 bytes server memory.
Mar 28 19:47:59 myhost collectd[1934]: tcpconns plugin: Reading from netlink succeeded. Will use 
the netlink method from now on.
Mar 28 19:47:59 myhost collectd[1934]: write_gcm: Asking metadata server for auth token
```

I have verified that the service is enabled.  When I check the permissions, it says I don't need to need special credentials since I am using GCE.  However, when I restart the stackdriver-extractor service, I get:

```
Please set STACKDRIVER_API_KEY in /etc/sysconfig/stackdriver
```

And so if I set that... I get:

```
stackdriver-extractor[3020]: Starting stackdriver-extractor: Unable to determine extractor endpoint! 
stackdriver-extractor[3020]: Unable to generate config file
```

I feel like something is wrong at the project level where this service is not getting the key information automatically like it is supposed to.

I dug into the scripts and found where it gets it...

```
curl -f -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/stackdriver-agent-key
```

But this is getting a 404.

Also, when I check the scopes:

```
# curl --silent -f -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud.useraccounts.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
```

Any ideas? My ultimate problem is that I can't create alerts on the process counts, but I think this is where Stackdriver gets it from.

Comment: Based on this document (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/authentication#cloud_monitoring_scopes) on GCE instance the APIs requires full access.

Comment: @Faizan At first I thought this fixed it when I rebuilt my VM, but it didn't.  What actually fixed this is... modifying the `/etc/sysconfig/stackdriver` file, adding in the `STACKDRIVER_API_KEY` WITH double quotes. I accidentally remove the double quotes apparently.

Comment: I'm glad to know your issue is resolved. Can you post your resolution as an answer so that I can benefit other users with the similar issue.

Comment: Will do, and thanks for the reply. I see now the order of events that I did that messed things up.  I'll document it. It all started with my messing up the COPY/PASTE of my API key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this problem, I fixed the API key. I accidentally left out the double quotes when I edited the file.

That brings me to the next point.  Why did I edit the file?  They provide a nice easy utility for adding an API key. We should use it.

```
/opt/stackdriver/stack-config --api-key DEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEF...
```

It will even restart the services for you.

As for how I got to this place to begin with... I accidentally copy/pasted a partial API key.  It wasn't obvious because I missed a little bit at the end. Little bits matter.

As for why I could not get this working by changing the scope to all API access, I don't know. I thought that would work as I really don't want to have to mess around with any more statefulness in my VM disk than I have to. But I'll take a working solution at this point.

One final bit of advice... if you are here, you might need to also find your API key. You can find it here:

https://app.google.stackdriver.com/settings/accounts/agent/

If one isn't there, you can create it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI the use of API keys is kind of depreciated/Legacy.
You should enable the Google Monitoring API and just install the agent.